# How do I check if an input box contains a specific character with HTML pattern attribute

Tags: html

With the HTML pattern attribute I am able to alert the user about for example the maximum or minimum lengths

```
pattern=".{3,3}" required title="Only 3 characters allowed"
```

I would however like to alert the user if the string misses a character.
Like the colon character in time.
I tried the following but that did not work:

```
pattern="/://ig" required title="Your time misses the colon"
```

The desired outcome is to alert the user if he forgets to use a colon in a time notation.

Comment: What does this have to do with `HTML`?

Comment: If it hasn't than what is it?

Comment: Well sorry, but we cannot somehow magically guess what you are working on. You cannot look over your shoulder to see the full code. You only dump some fragment here which could be anything. I do not see any html tags in that code.

Comment: Do you want the time in `hh:mm` or  `hh:mm:ss` format?

Comment: Without seconds Mr Geek (hh:mm)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
pattern="(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(:[0-5][0-9]){2}"
```

which will require time in this format: `HH:MM:SS`.

For other examples, check [this link](http://html5pattern.com/Dates).

**ANOTHER EDIT**

If you do not need the `seconds`, you can use:

```
pattern="(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])"
```

which *will* require time in `FORMAT: HH:MM`.

**Further Explanation**:

For the first part `(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])`, it simply means that the expected values can only be **in two digits** *(pick one digit from the other part, and one within the inner bracket)*, i.e. for `0[0-9]`, the expected value will fall within the range of `00`, `01`, `02`, `03` ... `09`. Same thing goes for `1[0-9]`, value can only be from `10`, `11`, `12`, to `19`. Also for `2[0-3]`, values can only be between `20`, `21`, `22` and `23` only.

So putting it together, `(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])` simply means the accepted values are digits from `00` to `23`, which is how the 24 hour time is calculated.

Then for the second part (after the **:** *of course*), the first `M` in the minute, can only accepts **one digit** between `0-5` and the second `M` can only accept **one digit** between `0-9`. Grouping it, then you'll have digit from `00 - 59`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Your update does not work, the one with the seconds works fine.

Comment: @Dummy, have you checked my updated answer? I've tested it and it works!

Comment: Hey @Dummy, can you test my updated answer and let me know if it works? :)

Answer (score 0):

For time inputs, use HTML's `<input type="time">`:

```html
<label>Time: <input type="time" value="00:00" min="00:00"></label>
```

Comment: it does not give any notification or whatsoever if something wrong is entered

Comment: @Dummy There can be nothing wrong with this time input, it's programmed to accept only valid numbers (times), so if you use it, you won't have to worry about errors.